# Raphael transparent element onclick

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

How can I make a fill of the transparent element in Raphael clickable? After specifying fill:"none" for an element (e.g. rect) only a frame is clickable. I need to put fill:"none" in order to make other elements from previous layers visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SVG you would normally use `pointer-events`, but Raphael does not support them (as there's no equivalent in VML). The way to accomplish clickable transparent fills in Raphael is to specify a fill with zero transparency with a transparent fill, i.e. `fill: "rgba(0,0,0,0)"` or specify any fill and then `fill-transparency: 0`.